# What is the difference between $ip and iptables in Linux?

Tags: linux, iptables

I am doing a project on securing a Linux system. We are going into VI to change a script for what the system allows. It is partially completed.

In the screenshot below, you can see that it has been filled out to allow port 22, but the line starts with `$ip`. The statement we use begins with `iptables`. Are these the same command? Or do they mean something totally different?

I wasn't able to find much online to explain the difference.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: We dont know where this file is comming from and therefor it‘s hard to answer. How is this file executed? Maybe you could do an ˋecho $ipˋ somewhere in this file and have a look on the output.

Comment: I don't need any help on the code, i'm just curious about the difference in commands (ip vs iptables)

Comment: The difference in commands is **based** on the code.

Comment: `vi` is a just text editor like Notepad, and not related to the question. You appear to be writing a shell script, so `$ip` is shell syntax for "insert the value of a variable called ip". If further up the script you have `ip=iptables` then it's the same. If `ip` is not defined, it's invalid. If you have `ip=doom3` then it'll let you play Doom3 (if installed and configured). It's hard to say from this snippet alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`iptables` is a command.  Each line in the script that begins with `iptables` runs the `iptables` command.

`$ip` is an environment variable that presumably contains the name of a command to run.  Each line in the script that begins with `$ip` runs the command whose name is contained in the `$ip` variable.

You're asking us to tell you what your variable is set to.  We have no idea.

Comment: Gotcha. That makes sense! Sorry--new to VI and fairly new to linux, too. Just trying to understand as much as possible. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please close off-topic questions.

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the file fragment you have provided, the file you are editing could be a shell script (bash, sh, etc). Since `iptables` is a valid linux command, that is probably the case. The file could also be perl, php, or another language which supports $variable syntax.

Look at the first line of the file, does it begin with `#!` (sh-bang)? ex:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Depending upon the script language being used to interpret your file, the `$ip` token could be resolved to be whatever the current value of $ip contains. Suppose that `ip=iptables`. Then it is likely that the file fragment you gave *should be* equivalent to the following:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
# put your dport ACCEPT rules here
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3398 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Which seems redundant, since the fourth line repeats the first.

Since the command `iptables` must be run as root to change the system firewall, there is a significant difference between `iptables` and `$ip` w.r.t. security.

If this file is writeable by a bad actor, the bad actor can revise the file to produce malicious behavior. But those changes would be detected.

Suppose the bad actor is able to change the value of the $ip variable? The a bad actor can inject malicious behavior into that script.

For example, suppose the variable is set to a command,

```
export ip='echo beat me bad ||iptables'
```

And then later the user naively sudo's to root and executes the script (file),

```
$ sudo -u root
$ $ip
beat me || <iptables runs here>
```

You could read about editing iptables rules [here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_edit_iptables_rules)

Policy rule: never use command interpolation for security sensitive files such as scripts that require root privilege (or could be run as root) (*such as the above script (file)*).

Suppose the bad actor could change your PATH environment variable, and inject a path another executable named `iptables`. When running commands & scripts as root, one needs to be cautious with paths. Consider using full path names to commands (or checking that PATH has not been corrupted); example:

```
/usr/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
# put your dport ACCEPT rules here
/usr/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3398 -j ACCEPT
/usr/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Policy rule: either explicitly check PATH when running as root, or use full paths to commands to ensure that commands are not redirected.